# Does 2:54 proved death punishment for apostasy?

Tags: quran, quran-translation, apostasy

Quran [2:54] states that calf worshipers were punished by death by their own people. Doesn't that prove death punishment for apostates according to Quran?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. There were a number of laws specific to the past nations. Examples are dietary laws of the Children of Israel, the laws of the people/family of Ya`qub (as), the laws specific to Adam (as) and his progeny.

Comment: @LifeH2O **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate.  I would recommend you read through the following help centre article regarding the constructive use of comments: http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment